# ReferenceError: users is not defined when trying to connect to postgres

Tags: javascript, node.js, postgresql, node-postgres

i have been following this video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ufdHsFClAk0 and in 32:54 when the guy got the result i got an error ReferenceError: users is not defined. here is my code so far

```
const {Client} = require('pg')
const users = [{ id: 1 }] 
const client = new Client({
    user: "postgres",
    password: "testing",
    host: "BlackPearl",
    port: 5432,
    database: users
})

execute()

async function execute(){
    await client.connect()
    console.log("Connected")
    const results = await client.query("select * from users")
    console.table(results.rows)
    await client.end()
    console.log("Disconnected")
}
```

and [here is what i see in pgAdmin4](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dO1mX.png)

that's my package.json

```
{
  "name": "expr",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "experiment.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "node experiment.js"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "pg": "^8.7.1"
  }
}
```

in the terminal i write `npm run test`

Comment: The line that reads `database: users` is where your error is. You haven't written `const users = [{ id: 1 }]` or anything like that.

Comment: @t56k didn't help :(

Comment: @t56k, in `database: users` `database` is referring to a database name not an array of users. So `users` should either be quoted as the actual string for the database name or be a variable that was declared earlier as being a name.

Comment: My point was more that it had to be defined as *something*, but fair

Comment: @Adrian Klaver, that's was the case, thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

change this:

```
const client = new Client({
    user: "postgres",
    password: "testing",
    host: "BlackPearl",
    port: 5432,
    database: users
})
```

to this:

```
const client = new Client({
    user: "postgres",
    password: "testing",
    host: "BlackPearl",
    port: 5432,
    database: 'users'
})
```

database name should be a string, not a reference, if it's called differently (not `users`) use the proper name